# "geckodriver" executable needs to be in PATH Pycharm

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

My code is:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://python.org')

driver.close()
```

The error is:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Aleksandra\PycharmProjects\YoutubeRG\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 76, in start
    stdin=PIPE)
  File "C:\Users\Aleksandra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 769, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\Aleksandra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1172, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden`

`During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:`

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Aleksandra/PycharmProjects/YoutubeRG/youtubemain.py", line 3, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "C:\Users\Aleksandra\PycharmProjects\YoutubeRG\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 164, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Users\Aleksandra\PycharmProjects\YoutubeRG\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 83, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.`

I put the path to geckodriver in the systemvariable's path:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DiuGv.png

What else can I do? I am lost.

Comment: You probably have to restart PyCharm to renew environment vars, or explicitly put it in PATH before running your test.